# .NET Scaffolding Failed

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to learn .NET, and I follow a tutorial from here [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code).

I was using Visual Studio Code, I can't use Visual Studio because it keeps freezing thanks to my hdd. Anyway when I'm trying to scaffold my controller, I get an error:

> PS C:\Users\User\TodoApi> dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TodoItemsController -async -api -m TodoItem -dc TodoContext -outDir Controllers
>
> Scaffolding failed.
> Failed to get Project Context for C:\Users\User\TodoApi\TodoApi.csproj.
>
> To see more information, enable tracing by setting environment
> variable 'codegen_trace' = 1. RunTime 00:00:01.09

And here is my `TodoApi.csproj` :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have followed the instruction but ended up with this error, and I don't know how to solve this, the instruction is fine when I've tried running it in Visual Studio, but since I'm still using hdd it keeps freezing every time, even when I'm just trying to type something.

Anyone have an solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you add a database context as specified in [that guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#add-a-database-context)?

Comment: Try updating dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator to latest stable using "dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"

Comment: @MatJ yes i already follow the guide and add the models

Comment: @Jeevan turns out i just need to update the dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator, and now it works thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the mentioned preview version(6.0.0-preview.7.21413.1) of *dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator* on the documentation page.
Updating the *dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator* to the latest stable version would fix the issue.

```
dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

I have created [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/24419) to update the documentation.

Update :
Now MS Doc is updated correctly.